# displaying group permissions causing duplicate queries in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

TLDR : I wanted to serialize a Group along with its permissions name. But lot of duplicate queries of content_type from Permission Model occurred. I tried to solve it through prefetch, but didn't work. What am i doing wrong?

so my serializer for retreive method is given below

```
class RetrieveGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_set = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    permissions = PermissionsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name', 'user_set', 'permissions')
```

The serializer for list method is given below

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_set = UserSerializer(many=True)
    permissions = PermissionsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'user_set', 'permissions')
```

the views is given below

```
class GroupViewSet(
                   mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    Creates, Updates, and retrives User Groups
    """

    queryset = Group.objects.all().prefetch_related('user_set').prefetch_related('permissions__content_type')
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        IsAuthenticated,
    )
    action_serializer_classes = {
        "create": CreateGroupSerializer,
        "retrieve": RetrieveGroupSerializer,
        "update": UpdateGroupSerializer
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        try:
            return self.action_serializer_classes[self.action]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            return super(GroupViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()
```

When I use the list method I am not facing any duplicate queries, but when I use the retrieve method on any single group instance I am getting lot of duplicate queries. 
[image: django-debug-toolbar output]

As you can see the content_type from Permission Model is getting queried 62 times. 
So I used prefetch_related on the Foreign Key in Permission Model. But the result is the same.

But the same queryset works well for the List method and doesn't cause duplicate queries. you can see that below
[image]

Other than the problem of duplicate queries I am also confused how can the same queryset cause such different results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's likely because the browsable API also displays a create / update form that has a dropdown with the content types and won't use the prefetch optimizations.
Try to get it as JSON and see how many requests it performs or remove the permissions on updates to see if it changes the query quantities.

Comment: Thanks. the problem was not there while just using JSON.

Comment: I was going crazy with those duplicates, thank you for this answer.

Comment: Glad this helped. Unfortunately, this isn't obvious that the create/update forms also needs some DB queries to display themselves.